# How to open Trello urls in Android/iOS app

Tags: android, url, filter, url-scheme, trello

I need to find a way to write working Trello url which includes filters and can be recognized by mobile apps.

I need this url to be recognized by Trello Android/iOS app. Trello app would automatically open itself with the filters pre-applied after clicking on the link, for example: 
I need to create an url which after clicking on it in a browser redirects a user to Trello Android app and shows only cards with label = important (url example: https://trello.com/b/NdwRiUrT/list?menu=filter&filter=label:important)

I found this article http://help.trello.com/article/824-sharing-links-to-cards-and-boards, and linking to cards and boards work easily, it is precisely how I would expect it to work:

1. user clicks the link
2. Trello Android app recognizes the link
   and opens up
3. user is shown only the card in the link

**Is there an easy way to achieve this with filters included in the url?**

Comment: Hi Poky - the URL's used on the Trello desktop website will open by default in the Trello app in Android (if installed), with the same settings (filters/specific card etc), so you just need to be able to generate or grab those URL's somehow. Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Mike, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, what you say is not true, I already tested that out (both iOS and Android) and it doesn't work. Yes, the URL will open in Trello app but unfortunately  with no filters applied. Basically, any parameters in the URL are being ignored, I am just being redirected to the correct board but with all the cards displayed, regardless the filter used. Direct links to cards, comments, boards work just fine. I am having trouble with passing along these parameters.

Comment: Apologies, I noticed now that the filters don't load but you can get the correct card (must have been tired). Good luck with your efforts though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the url with deep linking with firebase. When click operation perform then the url will redirect to the mobile app. Please refer below code which i have implemented in node js.

```
request({
    url: "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=YourAppKey",
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      "dynamicLinkInfo": {
        "dynamicLinkDomain": "domain",
        "link": "your url",
        "androidInfo": {
          "androidPackageName": "trello app package name",
          "androidFallbackLink": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=trello app package name&hl=en",
          "androidMinPackageVersionCode": "1",
          "androidLink": "Your link",
        },
        "iosInfo": {
          "iosBundleId": "trello app bundle ID",
          "iosCustomScheme": "App name",
          "iosIpadBundleId": "trello app bundle ID",
          "iosAppStoreId": "trello app store ID"
        },
        "socialMetaTagInfo": {
          "socialTitle": "App title",
          "socialDescription": "description",
          "socialImageLink": "Icon link if any"
        }
      },
      "suffix": {
        "option": "SHORT"
      }
    },
    json: true
  }
```